# Facebook "cross-domain receiver URL" application error

Tags: php, facebook

It needs Facebook facepile plugin(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile). I tried but I am getting this error

> (The Facebook Connect cross-domain receiver URL (http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php#?=&cb=f223d517566e616&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fpromolife.com.au%2Ff3e13728ba8ec8&relation=parent.parent&transport=postmessage) must have the application's Connect URL (http://www.testsite.com.au/) as a prefix. You can configure the Connect URL in the Application Settings Editor.)

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Could you post a piece of code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your connect URL must be the same as the URL you are running the script on & the callback URL. When I say the same I also mean EXACTLY the same in the sense of whether you are using http://yoursite or http://www.yoursite. Double check your app settings to make sure for no typo's in the connect URL also.